# create year column with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a timestamp column and I want to create a year column from this colum. I know how to show it but I am not able to create a column on my dataset. So far I have tried this:

```
data = data.withColumn('Year', data.select(year(('Date')))
```

But it throws an error saying:

> AssertionError: col should be Column

I am able to show the year doing this:

```
data.select(year('Date').alias('Year')).show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give a column to year function. Following would work:

`data = data.withColumn('Year', year(col('Date')))`

Answer (score 1):

Spark's data model can be a bit confusing.

Spark SQL functions and UDFs operate on "Column" objects. A Column in Spark is a *placeholder* for the column in the actual table. Some methods like `.select()` let you use strings as shortcuts, e.g. `df.select('year')` is equivalent to `df.select(pyspark.sql.functions.col('year'))`.

So [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172835/2954547) is correct because, instead of using a string, it correctly uses the column placeholder.

(This behavior is very poorly documented in my opinion.)